# How to activate webgpu backend on Tensorflow.JS

Tags: tensorflow.js

Current release on Github of Tensorflow.js includes a WEBGPU backend, but when running `tf.getBackend()` I get `webgl` even with Chrome Canary with WEBGPU enabled. Also running `tf.backend()` doesn't seem to indicate that WEBGPU is there.

Comment: Afaik it is only supported in chrome canary for macos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which `tf` package are you importing? The WebGPU backend is not bundled with `tfjs` by default - you need to import it specifically, like this:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu';

const init = async () => {
    await tf.ready();

    // Now we can create tensors and run ops.
    tf.matMul(a, b).print(); 
};

init();
```

Note that the backend is asynchronous - you have to call `await tf.ready()` before doing anything with it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

That is still an experimental feature. You can import the package with npm

```
 npm install @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu
```

And import it

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgpu';
```

The only thing to keep in mind is to await the backend

```js
import * as tf
(async() => {
  await tf.ready 
 // then do all operations on the backend
})()
```

Comment: The repo you linked to is out of date :) Please use this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-backend-webgpu